# feature make language more functional?

Tags: functional-programming

For each of the following language features, circle “functional” if having the
feature makes a language more of a functional language and “not” if it does not:

`A. closures functional not
 B. arrays functional not
 C. dynamic types functional not
 D. garbage collection functional not
 E. a read-eval-print loop`

`A` is **functional**

`B` is **not functional**

`C` is **not functional**

`D` is **functional**

`E` is **not functional**

These are the answers given to me, can anyone help explain what makes these either **functional** or **not functional**?

Comment: Ask whoever asked it to you. The question and the answers make very little sense.

Comment: Agree with the above, fairly confusing question though. I think your answers are probably "right" based on how it's worded. That is to say, it seems like those are the answers the question is wanting you to provide.

Comment: these are the answer that are given so they are correct, I am just slightly confused on what makes them correct or not correct. My professor explained it but wanted to see if I could gather an explanation that would make more sense to me

Comment: @bkennedy there is a chance that your professor is highly opinionated.